# MATLAB expression 'Mf' is not of the correct sparseness

Tags: sparse-matrix, mex, matlab-coder

Hello Im trying to transform a function to a .mex function through the command "coder". One of my inputs is a sparse double matrix. when the coder asks to define the type of the variable 'Mf' I setit as a double(:inf x :inf). it builts it and when it comes to run the function it stops with the following message: "MATLAB expression 'Mf' is not of the correct sparseness"

I would appreciate any suggestions and solutions. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MATLAB Coder does not currently support [sparse matrices](http://www.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ug/matlab-language-features-supported-for-code-generation.html?searchHighlight=matlab%20language%20features).

Depending upon the size of the data, you may consider converting the inputs to full matrices before calling your MEX function.

If the purpose of generating a MEX function is to speed up parts of your code, you could consider generating MEX functions for the functions in your code which do not require sparse and call those from your other MATLAB code. This way, you could accelerate parts of the code and still use sparse where required.